# Electrical engineer but new to embedded, help with programming a board first time

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, programming

I have researched and got all my components with my co worker, we are making a PCB and about to send to board house, but im not a super big programmer.

Once you get a board , how do you setup and program it? We have a jtag, and are using a texas instruments CPU, but how do i start once the board is here? I'd like to tryand get some knowledge without my co worker to make me seem more knowledgeable. I love using arduinos and have done alot, but nothing with a more industrial based processor.

If anyone has any guides, or the steps to take they would be appreciated lots!

Comment: Programming the device will be explained in the programmer's manual.  In general though unless your system comes with some kind of bootloader already burned into ROM, you'll probably have to use JTAG or a similar programming interface to write a bootloader to memory.

Comment: You say "CPU", but I assume you mean a microcontroller.  If you would _edit your question_ with the part number of the CPU that'll help us give you specifics.  Most likely, it's a microcontroller rather than a bare CPU, it has its own on-board flash, and you can just program it with JTAG.  For a lot of projects (and products, for that matter) there's no need to go beyond JTAG programming.

Comment: TI make a lot of different processors,  eg ARM, MSP32 and  8051 familys. Anyway check the datasheets for the processor so see how it can be programmed. JTAG is a good guess - most microprocessors and flash ROMs can be progreammed via JTAG.

Comment: papaya avata, I gather you want to look "smart" to someone else. You have some experience with arduino. But that's not likely to be of much help here. This is, in fact, one of the ways I separate the "embedded programmer" from the run-of-the-mill programmer. The added knowledge required to deal with linker definition files, the knowledge to understand the difference between a BOR, a POR, and a PUC. Or what's important to gather from CPU bugs found in the errata sheets. Arduino programmers would largely be "lost" in the weeds here. There isn't a simple answer for you, my opinion.

Comment: there should be a dev board for your chosen microcontroller. Refer to the documentation for that to find out how to get it up and running. Realistically, you should have started with said board, got the required experience then make your own pcb. Many dev boards have the debugger interface on them and allow you to connect your pcb to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about physically flashing in the program via JTAG, there are manuals provided by Texas instruments for that.

https://www.ti.com/design-resources/embedded-development/ccs-development-tools.html

If you are asking "how do I go about writing an embedded program"...  Start with the requirements and work from there.

There are some things that will be different when writing embedded code for your own hardware.

1. Its likely your program will be written in C, assembly language, or some combination of those two.  While C++ is possible in embedded environments, its often not the best fit.
2. Compared to say a PC, in an embedded environment you typically have much less memory and processing power.  Writing things efficiently is going to be more important.  Avoiding dynamic memory allocation when possible is probably a good idea.
3. This is your board.  So, unlike an Arduino there is probably not going to be a bunch of libraries that you can just import and use.  Expect to spend a lot of time looking at the processor datasheets and figuring out how to configure all the hardware registers.
4. Unless this is a higher end embedded system running an embedded operating system like Linux you aren't going to have access to lots of predefined services and function calls.  Typically, the best you can expect is the C standard library and possibly some hardware configuration functions / code generation provided by the processor vendor.

Answer (score 1):

I am more familiar with Microchip PICs and their compilers, programmers and debuggers, but TI should have the same sort of tools. It would be helpful to use a simulator so you can write programs for the device without having the actual hardware. Some simulation tools can provide virtual peripherals and interactive components, so you might search for those to see if they will work for your device and overall design.

One place to start might be: https://www.ti.com/design-resources/design-tools-simulation/models-simulators/overview.html

Also try MATLAB and SimuLink: https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/81/Running-CCS-and-Matlab.pdf

This might help: [https://engineering.purdue.edu/~ece495/Power_Electronics_Lab/exp2.pdf](https://engineering.purdue.edu/%7Eece495/Power_Electronics_Lab/exp2.pdf)

Proteus is another powerful tool that some engineers use, but I have no direct experience: https://edasim.com/en/microcontroller-co-simulation/

Depending on your programming experience, you might search for various tutorials that target the devices you will be using. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to familiarize yourself with the tool chain and to make sure it works.

To get a better understanding of the building process, avoid highly integrated IDEs, use your favorite text editor with source code highlighting, and the command line. You can later migrate to any IDE you like best.

Since you have an Arduino background, start with a simple Blinky program, using empty loops for delay. Strive to stop the compiler from optimizing the loops away. If it does, and you cannot stop it, give it a shrug and use your oscilloscope to see an output pin "blink".

If that works, replace the loops with timers, and then move on in the direction you see fit for your final application.

Write separate small experiment programs for any feature you want to use.

Learn about software architecture and design, separate abstraction layers. You might want to search for provided hardware abstraction layers (HAL) or write your own for your needs.